# Not able to lookup datasource configured in jboss 7.x using Spring JNDIObjectfactorybean

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss7.x, datasource, jndi

I have configured datasource in Jboss 7.x as below:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyWebAppDS" pool-name="MyWebAppDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=sa1p</connection-url>
                <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa1</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

then in my spring application I am using below code to look up datasource:

```
 <bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:jboss/datasources/MyWebAppDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but when I deploy the application I get below exception:

> CreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'jndiDataSource'**
>   defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method faile **nested exception is**
>   **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up**
>   **jboss/datasources/MyWebAppDS, service service**
>   **jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MyWebAppDS is not started**
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
>   [spring-beans-3.1. ELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.R ASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.REL E.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3
>   1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEA jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RE SE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
>   [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
>   [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>   [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up
>   jboss/datasources/MyWebAppDS, service service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MyWebAppDS is no t started
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:132)
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:80)
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:120)
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.
>   1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.R ELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
>           ... 24 more

Am i missing anything  here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missing dependencies which was causing failure to start JNDI service.
I added sqljdbc4.jar %jboss-home%\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\main which resolved my problem.